# Кастомный listview из файла

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь вывести из файла в кастомный listview возникают конфликты с типами помогите исправить что не так

Так подключаю файл :

```
public List<String> getTextFromRaw() {
        List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stm);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                arr.add(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Так формирую список

```
listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tst);
        List<String> arr = getTextFromRaw();
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> date = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(arr.length);
        Map <String, Object> map;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("name",arr[i]);
            map.put("n",a);
            date.add(map);
        }
        String [] from = {"name","n"};
        int[] to = {R.id.tv1,R.id.tv};
        // Создаём адаптер SimpleAdapter, чтобы привязать массив к ListView
        SimpleAdapter ad = new SimpleAdapter(number_1.this,date,R.layout.test2,from,to);

        // Привяжем массив через адаптер к ListView
        listView1.setAdapter(ad);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте `map.put("name",arr[i]);` на `map.put("name",arr.get(i));` и
`arr.length` на `arr.size()`

Comment: (arr.length); length выделяет красным

Comment: @Joel дополнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо заработало